# android overflow menu item text not displayed

Tags: android

*See end of post for a workaround*

I added an overflow menu to my main Android Action. However when pressing the [...] in the top right corner, the PopupMenu does not display the menu items correctly. They are left blank, see the image, it should contait 2 menu items with the strings "Manage" and "About":

[image: Expanded overflow menu with invisible items]

This problem only arises for the MainActivity, i.e. the Activity starting at application launch. A secondary Activity, that is spawned later, correctly displays menu items.

The Items do get added to the menue somehow, since the box changes its size with more/less menu items. Also I do get a response when clicking where a menu item is supposed to be, e.g. show a Toast with some text.

Adding the menu items with `showAsAction="always"` will display the item correctly with it's icon in the ActionBar.

The MainActivity was initially created as a PageView Activity, the Toolbar was then later added to it's layout.

***Edit***
Making the menu items checkable with `android:checkable="true"` will show a checkbox next to the empty spot where the text is supposed to be.

`layout/main_activity.xml`:

```xml
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PickupList.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/purple_200"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/teal_200" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`layout/main_menu.xml`:

```xml
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainmenu_manage"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        android:title="@string/activitymain_menu_manage" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainmenu_about"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:title="@string/activitymain_menu_abount" />
</menu>
```

`themes/themes.xml` (almost unchanged):

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.PickupList" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.PickupList.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.PickupList.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.PickupList.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</resources>
```

`MainAction.java`:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        // works fine
        if (id == R.id.mainmenu_about) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.mainmenu_manage) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "manage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the code-dump. I am at my wits end with what else I can do here.

***Edit / Workaround:***

So in the end I came up with a workaround.

- I manually added a menu item with the icon for the overflow menu to the Toolbar and set its `showAsAction="always"` property.
- In the click handler I then create custom [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu) and anchor it to the Toolbar with `Gravity.END`.
- The PopupMenu will then display it's items correctly.

I do not mark this solution as an answer, although it effectively solves my problem. It solves the problem with the bad aftertaste, that the android api has defeated me and I still have hope that I (or someone else) sees an error and comes up with a solution that uses the internal overflow menu mechanics.

Comment: I believe it's white on white. Make sure if it is so by long clicking on an item so that the ripple effect can make the text , if white, readable. Then report back!

Comment: May be white text color?

Comment: @PrinceAli Good idea, i haven't noticed that the ripple effect is also not visible (I assume you mean the coloring of the item background from the middle towards the edges). So no text, no background color change on click.
I also tried to set the TextColor manually in ```onPrepareOptionsMenu()``` without success

Comment: Still the same without the android:theme

Comment: I'm not familiar with androidx or MaterialComponents. Try searching this site for a similar issue! Also, try @mentioning other people when commenting because we don't get notified otherwise. At least I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem you described, no ripple effect whatsoever, but got a response while clicking in the white box from the menu.
Fixed it by adding the following line in my styles.xml

```
<item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
```